# How can I change the whitespace above and below center?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, environments

Is it possible to control the space above and below `center`, e.g. the way it can be controlled above and below math display? In other words, is there an equivalent to, say,

```
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{3pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

Comment: Do you mean `\begin{center}`? Use `\centering` within a group. Say, `\bgroup \centering ... your code ... \egroup'. You can use `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` or simply enclose the code between `{}` to form a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your `mycenter` environment and pass a length (optionally) to modify the top/bottom gap:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\newenvironment{mycenter}[1][\topsep]
  {\setlength{\topsep}{#1}\par\kern\topsep\centering}% \begin{mycenter}[<len>]
  {\par\kern\topsep}% \end{mycenter}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this MWE
\begin{document}
1: \lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
  2: \lipsum[2]
\end{center}
3: \lipsum[2]
\begin{mycenter}
  4: \lipsum[2]
\end{mycenter}
5: \lipsum[2]
\begin{mycenter}[0pt]
  6: \lipsum[2]
\end{mycenter}
7: \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) were loaded specifically for this MWE, and may not be needed in your final document.

Answer (score 8):

The `center` environment is actually defined in terms of a `list`, so you can tweak all the parameters detailed in Section 56 of `source2e`.

In terms of the spacing above the `center` environment, you can use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\oldcenter\center
\let\oldendcenter\endcenter
\renewenvironment{center}{\setlength\topsep{0pt}\oldcenter}{\oldendcenter}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The spacing below could be controlled by adding some glue at the end of the environment (after `\oldendcenter`).

Comment: Just to make sure: is it that that `\topsep` influences both top and bottom margin, isn't it?

Comment: I want to control the space above and below the center environment but only in certain instances and \setlength\topsep{0pt} controls space both above and below
\begin{center}
xxx  \end{center}

Comment: @tohecz Yes, it would be nice to control them separately but I can live with \topsep.

Comment: @tohecz `\topsep` influences top separation, not bottom

Comment: @user15042 it wasn't obvious that you wanted to have only certain instances; I assumed you wanted to change all of them. Looks like Werner has given a way to do certain instances

Comment: How to remove the bottom space? It is not clear from your answer. Please let me know.