# Distributing two small images in a document (horizontally) evenly

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

Consider the following code (no special packages added)

```
\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{black_square} and \includegraphics{black_square}
\par\end{center}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 
\end{document}
```

that produces the output [image], where the black squares stand for some image I wand to put in my document.

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to add images to a document ? I'm vaguely aware that there are some floating environments available for this, but I want the images at exactly this specific place.
2. How can I rearrange the black square so that they are horizontally evenly distributed and the "and" is vertically in the middle, i.e. more like this: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\includegraphics` places images upon the text baseline, I here use `\raisebox` to shift the figures down (1/2 of their height - 1/2 the height of a textline).  Then, by placing symmetric `\hspace`s around the word "and", I can achieve a symmetric layout.  I use `%` at the end of the lines to prevent stray spaces from getting introduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 

\begin{center}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{black_square}}%
\hspace{.5in}%
and%
\hspace{.5in}%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{black_square}}
\par\end{center}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the figures to be **exactly** spaced between the margin and the middle text, this would suffice, replacing the `center` environment with the appropriate `\hfil`s, making sure to not indent the "paragraph" on which the figures appear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 

\medskip
\noindent
\hfil%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{black_square}}%
\hfil%
and%
\hfil%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{black_square}}%
\hfil%
\par\medskip

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 

\medskip
\noindent
\hfil%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1.3in,height=1.3in]{black_square}}%
\hfil%
and%
\hfil%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-.5\height+.5\ht\strutbox}%
  {\includegraphics[width=1.3in,height=1.3in]{black_square}}%
\hfil%
\par\medskip

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "`\includegraphics` places images upon the text baseline" ? Why exactly is the space between the text above and below the picture the same if you raise it ?

Comment: I'm also confused by the `\medskip \noindent \hfil%` before the picture and the `\medskip` after it from your second code sample. Is this just a replacement for `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` ?

Comment: @user10324 To your Q1, if you type `xyz\includegrphics{}`, the bottom of the image will be aligned with the bottom of the `x` (the baseline).  So, one must either raise the text, or lower the figure to achieve your vertical centering goal.  I chose to lower the figures.

Comment: @user10324 To Q2, the reason I eliminated the `center` environment is that it plays some havoc with the "intensity", for lack of a better word, of the `\hfil` macros.  One can often use centering, and adjust the fills to some judicious combination of `\hfil` and `\hfill`, but I thought it easier to avoid the `center` environment altogether.  The `\medskip`s are just a way to add some vertical gap, which otherwise would have come from the `center` environment.

Comment: @user10324 Back to Q1, `\height` will contain the height of the `\includegraphics` image, whereas `\ht\strutbox` is the height of one line of text.  So, mathematically, if you wish to center two objects of those respective heights, the net adjustment has to be 1/2 the difference of those two heights.  And that is the value of my adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. One last question: Is the vertical gap that comes from the `center` precisely `\medskip` or is it a different value ?

Comment: @user10324 I do not know for sure the gap associated with `center`.  However, `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, and/or `\bigskip` are commonly used by environments in that capacity.

Comment: @user10324 cmhughes answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74212/how-can-i-change-the-whitespace-above-and-below-center/74215#74215 talks a bit more about the default gaps of the `center` environment.  It would appear to be the lengths `\topsep` and (I am inferring here) `\bottomsep`.

Answer (score 2):

> Answer with `\hfill`. But `and` is not vertically centered.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{black_square} \hfill  and  \hfill \includegraphics{black_square}
\par
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> Answer with 'subcaption' Now `and` is vertically centered.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
      \end{subfigure}
\hfill and \hfill
      \begin{subfigure}{0.31\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
      \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
some text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second example looks good. But two issues remain: 1) In the second example you provided, I think you first have to add `\usepackage{caption}` otherwise it throws an error. 2) How can I add text before the figure ? Placing text before `\begin{figure}` still moves it after the figure when compiled.

Comment: https://www.writelatex.com shows no error. Now result ok?

Comment: Yes, though I accepted the other answer because it was slightly more detailed and also did without the `subcaption` package. Thank you nonetheless for your effort, I upvoted you.